# Convergence in probability of a non decreasing Sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let's say we have a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ such that $\forall n X_n \leq X_{n+1}$ a.s that converges in probability to $X$. Can we say that $\forall n, X_n \leq X$ almost surely ?

Thank you for your answer,

Comment: (I'm guessing that you intend the *sequence* to be non-decreasing, in the sense that $X_n\le X_{n+1}$ a.s. for each $n$.) 

Do you know about the fact that if a sequence of random variables converges in probability, then it admits  a subsequence that converges a.s.?

Comment: Yes I know that fact. I guess the way I leaned it is that for each subsequence, we can construct a subsequence such that we have the convergence a.s
I guess all we have to do to  prove it for each $n$ is to select a subsequence that contains that integer, and then apply this result to show the inequality.
Is this correct ?

Comment: Sorry I this it is a wrong argument because we don't know for sure that the choses index will be in the second subsequence. I think we can do it by supposing that $X_n > X$ for some $n$ and it follows that $X_k > X $ for all $k > n$
then using the subsequence argument will give a contradiction.
I hope the argument is correct this time